# Need help to understand the solutionsheet. Fourier

Tags: fourier-analysis

Im suposed to find the fouries coeffisient from the expression:

$$f(x) = 5-4cos(2x)-2sin(5x)+5cos(8x)$$

I do understand that a_0 will be 5, but I struggle to find a_n and b_n. I looked at the solutionsheet from my professor, but i dont quite see/ understand the mindset behind finding the coeffisients:

[image]

1. I dont understand how i can see that f(x) has the period 2\pi
2. I do not undertand how he found a_n and b_n

Comment: He found $a_n,b_n$ by carrying out the integrals…

Comment: okay, so he just plot in f(x) in the integral? but i dont know what he means by saying using the orthogonality property of trigonometric system

Comment: @Lisa yes he just integrates $f(x)$ directly to get the coefficients. See my answer below to see how the coefficients are derived.

Comment: The function $f$ is _already in the form of a Fourier series as it is just a sum of sines and cosines_. If \begin{align} 5 - 4 \cos 2 x - 2 \sin 5x + 5 \cos 8x &= f(x) \\ &= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_{n} \cos(n x) + b_{n} \sin(n x) \\ &= a_{0} + a_{1} \cos x + b_{1} \sin x + a_{2} \cos 2x + b_{2} \sin 2x + \dots \end{align} then to get the coefficients you can just equate the two sides and read them off directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recall that the Fourier Series of a function with period $2\pi$  is defined as

$$f(x)=a_0 +\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin(nx)$$

An amazing property of trigonometric functions is [orthogonality](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) which means that

$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(kx)dx=0$$
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(kx)dx=0$$
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(nx)\cos(kx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(kx)\cos(nx)dx=0$$

If $n\ne k$
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx)\cos(kx)dx=0$$

$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(nx)\sin(kx)dx=0$$

and if $n=k$

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx)\cos(nx)dx=1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(nx)\sin(nx)dx=1$$
Where $n,k$ are integers greater than or equal to $0$.

Now let us integrate both sides of the Fourier Series such that

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(kx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left( a_0 +\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin(nx)\right)\cos(kx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi a_0\cos(kx)dx+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx)\cos(kx)dx+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(nx)\cos(kx)dx$$

We see from the previous identities that most of the integrals are wiped out leaving only

$$ \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(kx)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx)\cos(kx)dx$$

For the right hand side, because of orthogonality most of the terms of the series go to zero and the only term left is when $n=k$ so

$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(kx)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(nx)\cos(kx)dx=a_k\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(kx)\cos(kx)dx=a_k$$
So now we have a formula for the coefficients $a_n$. Then integrating both sides of the Fourier Series such

$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(kx)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left( a_0 +\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin(nx)\right)\sin(kx)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(nx)\sin(kx)dx=b_k\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(kx)\sin(kx)dx=b_k$$

Then finally integrating both sides from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi a_0 dx=a_0$$

Hopefully this gives you a sense of where the formulas for the Fourier Coefficients come from and you can make use of them for your problem. Also since $f(x)$ is made up of sines and cosines its period must be some multiple of $2\pi$ but since the only factor between $2$, $5$, and $8$ is $1$ then its period must be $2\pi$.

Comment: WOW, Thank you @aleden. this makes a lot of sense.